# Why does this exception claim the code doesn't write data?

Tags: c#, webclient, onedrive

If you run this code it will throw a WebException. The inner exception is "Content-Length or Chunked Encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data." and I do not understand the nature of the problem. Can anyone cast light into this dark corner?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace sandpit
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      string INITIAL_URI = "http://docs.live.net/SkyDocsService.svc";
      string SOAP = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><GetWebAccountInfoRequest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/clouddocuments\"><BaseRequest><ClientAppId>SkyDrive Service Client</ClientAppId><Market>en-US</Market><SkyDocsServiceVersion>v1.0</SkyDocsServiceVersion></BaseRequest><GetReadWriteLibrariesOnly>false</GetReadWriteLibrariesOnly></GetWebAccountInfoRequest></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
      using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
      {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "GetWebAccountInfo";
        wc.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US";
        wc.Headers["Accept"] = "text/xml";
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        string response = wc.UploadString(INITIAL_URI, SOAP);
        Debug.WriteLine(response);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `<GetReadWriteLibrariesOnly>false</GetReadWriteLibrariesOnly>` mean in this context?

Comment: GetReadWriteLibraries is a filter value in what is essentially a query. It's not relevant; if live.com didn't like my query I would have received a response that said so, not a send barf. Hans, I shall try the magical reboot spell and see if that flips my quantum bits back into a more sane universe.

Comment: I've noticed that I can get away with just <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" /> because I'm really only after the response headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is redirection by the webserver.

Unfortunately you have to subclass WebClient to fix this. This is harder than it looks because Silverlight (any flavour) doesn't like this and throws an inheritance related exception until you guess that you need to override the ctor and attribute it as SecurityCritical.

```
public class WebClient2 : WebClient
{
  [SecurityCritical]
  public WebClient2() : base() { }  
  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri address)
  {
    var wr = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    if (wr is HttpWebRequest)
      (wr as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    return wr;
  }
}
```

If you want to go further you could surface an AllowAutoRedirect property on WebClient2 and hook it all up.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a this [SkyDrive client](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/) instead of writing SOAP requests manually:

```
var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();
client.LogOn("user", "pwd");
var info = client.GetWebAccountInfo();
Console.WriteLine(info.Title);
```

Seems easier to me. But if you really insist on using a `WebClient` and handle the protocol manually you could see with Fiddler what's being exchanged over the wire with the .NET Client and replicate it. I think you might be missing to provide credentials to your request when working with the WebClient in order to authenticate.

If you look at the network level trace you will see that the SyDrive server requires Passport authentication which you will have to handle manually if you decide to go with the `WebClient` route which could be quite a lot of work:

```
Location: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1310230173&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fdocs.live.net:101%2FSkyDocsService.svc&lc=1033&id=250206
WWW-Authenticate: Passport1.4 ct=1310230292,rver=6.1.6206.0,wp=MBI,lc=1033,id=250206
```

Comment: Because the SkyDriveApiClient doesn't even work with VS2010 much less WP7.

Comment: As a matter of interest I lifted the soap *from* SkyDriveApiClient.

Comment: @Peter Wone, it's weird when you say that it doesn't work with VS2010, as the example in my answer worked perfectly fine when I tested it. For WP7 I agree. Some modifications might be required to port it. Also if you lifted this SOAP request from the client you should also *lift* the part that does the Passport authentication. SkyDrive has no official API so we, as developers, should do what we have :-)

Comment: I've just got it to work. It was a redirect. The problem was that I foolishly took notice of the Obsolete attribute on WebHttpRequest and as a result ran afoul of redirection because you have to *override* WebClient to get at the necessary attribute. As for my VS2010 issue, I'll take your word for it and have another crack at converting it, but honestly I'm more inclined to put together a REST based WCF interface and use that from both dek and phone. I have the REST API from Microsoft and contrary to some opinions MS is unlikely to change it since both Office and WP7 use the REST interface.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was redirection made by the same IIS server 6 because Session State Mode was set to 'autodetect' instead of 'use cookies'. Every URL request was redirected with 'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1'.

Answer (score -1):

You have just to change the URL service into : https://docs.live.net/SkyDocsService.svc